# Jquery Autocomplete in WIndows10/Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, autocomplete, windows-10

Many years i use in php codes  jquery autocomplete. Now many users upgrade system system Windows7 to Windows10. Functionality jquery  autocomplete not working in Windows 10 (browser Edge, Chrome).

But on only on some pc yes. More pc not working. Where is problem of this ? Settings any parameters windows, rowser or where.

There si code of autocomplete:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#dodavmeno").autocomplete("search_code.php", {
       width: 260,
       highlight: false,
       selectFirst: false,

    });
});
```

In search_code.php is part:

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select concat(dodavmeno,' //  ',dodavico) as course_name 
            from dodavatel where concat(dodavmeno,' //  ',dodavico) LIKE ? " ); 
$stmt->bindValue(1, "%$q%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(); 
if ( $stmt )
{
    foreach ($stmt as $row) 
    {
        $cname = $row['course_name'];
            echo "$cname\n";
        }
    }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found out windows 10 not support jquery autocomplete !